# find multiple occurences as part of larger pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string the looks like such:

```
string = 0.033 0.0331
string2   =  0.0022e+002  123.4
```

In this case the list of numbers is two for both strings, but this can be one or more.

I want to match the string and numbers such that I use the numbers and put them in a list. However I can't seem to match all the individual numbers. I use the following regex (example string as input):

```
matchNum = re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*=\s*((\d+\.?\d*e?[+-]?\d*)\s*)+', 'string2   =  0.0022e+002  123.4')
```

This however only returns the string and the last number (twice), like such:

```
[('String2', '123.4\n', '123.4')]
```

Any idea how I would be able to get this (?):

```
[('String2', '0.0022e+002', '123.4')]
```

As mentioned there can also be one or more numbers but there will always be one string in the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may collect the matches first, capturing the part before `=` into Group 1 
and the part after `=` into Group 2, and use a second regex to only extract the numbers. Here is a snippet that you may adjust further to suit any specific requirements:

```
import re
s = 'string2   =  0.0022e+002  123.4'
r1 = re.compile(r'(\S+)\s*=\s*((?:(?:-?\d+\.?\d*(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)\s*)+)', re.I)
r2 = re.compile(r'-?\d+\.?\d*(?:e?[+-]?\d+)?', re.I)
matches = r1.finditer(s)
res = []
for x in matches:
    tmp = [x.group(1)]
    tmp.extend(r2.findall(x.group(2)))
    res.append(tmp)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ALdcdp)

The `r1` regex finds the matches with all the data you need, and `r2` will extract the necessary numbers from Group 2 once there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye something like this:

```
import re

s = """
string = 0.033 0.0331
string2   =  0.0022e+002  123.4
string3 = 0.8291 
"""

rgx = re.compile(r'([^ \n]*) *= *([^ ]+) *([^ \n]+)?')
for x in rgx.finditer(s):
    print x.groups()

# ('string', '0.033', '0.0331')
# ('string2', '0.0022e+002', '123.4')
# ('string3', '0.8291', None)
```

You can use `print tuple(x for x in x.groups() if x)` if you don't need the `None`.

**[Edit]** Another aproach to support arbitrary quantity of numbers:

```
s = """
string = 0.033 0.0331
string2   =  0.0022e+002  123.4
string3 = 0.8291 
string4= 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
"""

rgx = re.compile('[^ \n=]+')
print [rgx.findall(l) for l in s.splitlines() if l]

# [['string', '0.033', '0.0331'], ['string2', '0.0022e+002', '123.4'], 
#  ['string3', '0.8291'], ['string4', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5']]
```